# Помогите новичку с заданием

Tags: c++

ЗАДАЛИ НАПИСАТЬ СУММУ ЧИСЕЛ НО НЕ ЗНАЮ КАК ВОТ ЧТО СДЕЛАЛ НО НЕ РАБТАЕТ

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int sum;
int main()
{
     x=1;
     y=2;
     sum=x+y;
     printf("Summa:",sum);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: "НО НЕ РАБТАЕТ" - Маленький гномик высовывается из компьютера и говорит: "НЕ РАБТАЕТ"?

Comment: @Igor КАКОЙ ЕЩЕ ГНОМИК КАк СДЕЛАТЬ ЧТОБ РАБОТАЛО?

Comment: Маленький компьютерный гномик.

Comment: А в спокойном тоне можно писать, без Капса?

Comment: @oligarh  Вам так намекают на опечатку скорее всего ...

Comment: Вот так -- `printf("Summa: %d\n",sum);` ([учитесь читать manpages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3p.html))

Comment: @Leks Нет. Ему намекают, что ошибку компиляции надо приводить в вопросе.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int sum;
int main()
{
    int x=1; //нужно указывать типы
    int y=2;
     sum=x+y;
     cout<<"Summa: "<<sum;// вывод в консоль через cout
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Впрочем IDE умеет находить и указывать на подобные ошибки. Учитесь читать коды ошибок.